# Using article 'The' in Noun + Prep + Noun pattern

Tags: articles

I have a doubt of using the article (`the`) in the following context. Please tell me which version of the following two sentences is correct?.

```
    1. A child pulled out **the** grass in the park near my home. [the grass]
    2. A child pulled out grass in the park near my home. [grass]
```

Comment: If you are learning English, you may find our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) more suited to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fully grammatical.

The second refers to some unspecified grass in the part that the child pulled, while the first indicates either all the grass in the park, or some particular grass that the hearer is expected to know.

Comment: I got the point. Thank you @ColinFine. You helped me to solve a problem which bothered me for a long time.